# Generate the SAME JOSE token between client and server (PHP-C#)

Tags: c#, php, encryption, jwt, jose

Well, I'm trying to generate the same key with this two libraries:

- https://github.com/dvsekhvalnov/jose-jwt this is for C#
- https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose and this is for PHP

I have implemented both:

#### In C#:

```
public static string CypherData<T>(T payload)
{
    return JWT.Encode(payload, pubkey, JweAlgorithm.RSA_OAEP, JweEncryption.A256GCM, JweCompression.DEF);
}

Console.WriteLine(Api.CypherData("hola"));
```

This how I load public key PEM string:

```
private static RSACryptoServiceProvider GetPubKey()
{
     ConnPreCheck();

     JObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(getPubKey.HttpGet());

     pubkeyStr = obj["data"]["pubKey"].ToString();

     return PemKeyUtils.GetRSAProviderFromPemString(pubkeyStr);
}
```

And this is what it returns:

> eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUCIsImVuYyI6IkEyNTZHQ00ifQ.L3Teg2RSXXpp4jakLkl2PQgidJ5BIXyP5QZM2B4RaO0vs55aT22D9_dPl6d83KvXezM4YkOnyoF0JA0eLX3k8W4eWkHUhgoYqxgwQSWWhjrpDxcpNdXbDlB6zVb_BKf5upro5qm23nr_SOkkqhKJGrw_sIXvD1LjOburLolDqojrnvK5awGtiFwkPZjRh_wh4z4buEfYsWJCKhTLU6aG_DipmbAXq1o9u1-cqiQJC0JlPJRbh6JJDmVc9YqBv0W0rFEa7W5HA12TO-RtV42tEPApr3hNmD8QwzvxxZYKpMzoBAsSQcvSKk878qeOAcx3pZyoDZ6WzD-LRusWy7nJwOa6AC9NsL91mv8WsZxWar9AnzOsKleSJ7k8I477pXE_H1g7XnFBgmA4egF-721sa7SO2LtS440v1ytA4504sdjVYeOfWmRSU4UljnUqaYTd031fzCevzNEO0Q7mncn-sJACVHiwQB9c703SvYZaFOyzU-vdXUqBRTR6x0JvQd_lFNgSS9pOQC5BQbAKOME9fjdXiwRUKfyHXCUAUj88CJEMqxg3_VYYfUC04GahmoysR9QUpK3l84Z5TLOi47SvO-NkR-2wf7v4ko8bZIR3E6XFHFG9lWwdzR_JPz7fm0OFiYB0HN8XgWE4bQ2tasYsmFhWVfkeRZodnlqFvImSNjA.GIGFv4h_nYkpBiA5.1_66eMEb.BJTezaLucvfluWQ8VEzgCQ

#### In PHP:

Well, the PHP implementation is the following:

```
include(__DIR__ . "/../libs/jose/autoload.php");

$file = __DIR__ . '/../keys/public.key';
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// This is the input we want to load verify.
$input = @$_GET["input"];

$key = new \Jose\KeyConverter\RSAKey($contents);

$jwe = \Jose\Factory\JWEFactory::createJWEToCompactJSON(
    $input,                    // The message to encrypt
    new \Jose\Object\JWK($key->toArray()),                        // The key of the recipient
    [
        'alg' => 'RSA-OAEP',
        'enc' => 'A256GCM',
        'zip' => 'DEF',
    ]
);
```

They are similar codes no?

But the output is different:

> eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUCIsImVuYyI6IkEyNTZHQ00iLCJ6aXAiOiJERUYifQ.jbNHUCuXYcXZWrHsJrPclV-fjYmFWwwPj4t3kAOt7PahQfsz0a1GaRrODcwKce4yRtLyjv2U7CtFMxt9ah3XTwIqm1mzzPMhO4LnFIRqMRgsxEgIijRqNOOpE85M3UPBRqjYw0wdjaqfJToLVLwaHgUPCkOqsHrdOOWkxN20fZYy4Z1PQAC0rk2WqLD0x7Za1jdV6LvVtd18iFIaRqf2uNYcRePdyInRxwHGp9JfRkVCQILTfwHlxQBKrwJxhZOzdHrjjNjxNsjAsHGMix6MAbUR0YT4hlrE59eriDVxix4uQrrChuzWVz_kY9-zvB9SDZnYDdfgONYUgTMpbkMTVWsF40JmWJ6wvGs3HaaIxN17UjQLemKgrS4-bqvbnschhZTIGi5-f8Cr_SwGo411VNYhNpD4P1H2dEjmAFpn3SdW3Oi6pPgK2tvIpEwGUS-Gi29-aCCNeuyE2m5dbFW28G9HMmvZHAky4KHE4NlNJTrH0aBxQX_Gc7eTf9q00gJtKQ5CinXaUYAB0xSEbsNACZuFLPawuxj_3FGn6dHYFOkSsatCTcqV5tiGJXG6ns-wDc682-G9Mj8HCIzYzakp-yZLIaY00fg5xQdgKJrk0QbCtvbwiQGoupyMV9f3RpEBJznPrq4STypxskdh6jksB6T_1fhPqZMVt2BHR4phCBg.9380DJUDH4TQnnr7.zEuMQwRr.BfdStBMcVnVR-2ujTLjuaA

You can see the differences here:

[image: ...]

Left is for C# and right for PHP. You can see it there: http://qbz28b-user.freehosting.host/html/Result.html

Obviously, when I try to decrypt with PHP the text generated with C#...

... the implementation of decrypting in PHP:

```
include(__DIR__ . "/../libs/jose/autoload.php");

$file = __DIR__ . '/../keys/private.key';
$contents = file_get_contents($file);

// This is the input we want to load verify.
$input = @$_GET["input"];

$jwk = new \Jose\KeyConverter\RSAKey($contents);

// We create our loader.
$loader = new Jose\Loader();
$loader->load($input);

// The payload is decrypted using our key.
$jws = $loader->loadAndDecryptUsingKey(
    $input,            // The input to load and decrypt
    new \Jose\Object\JWK($jwk->toArray()),              // The symmetric or private key
    ['RSA-OAEP'],      // A list of allowed key encryption algorithms
    ['A256GCM'],       // A list of allowed content encryption algorithms
    $recipient_index   // If decrypted, this variable will be set with the recipient index used to decrypt
);

$coreData["content"] = $jws->getPayload();
```

The following exception occurs:

> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Unable to decrypt the
>   JWE. in C:\xampp\htdocs\z3nth10n-PHP\libs\jose\Decrypter.php:80 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\z3nth10n-PHP\libs\jose\Loader.php(95):
>   Jose\Decrypter->decryptUsingKeySet(Object(Jose\Object\JWE),
>   Object(Jose\Object\JWKSet), NULL) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\z3nth10n-PHP\libs\jose\Loader.php(30):
>   Jose\Loader->loadAndDecrypt('eyJhbGciOiJSU0E...',
>   Object(Jose\Object\JWKSet), Array, Array, NULL) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\z3nth10n-PHP\includes\actions.php(321):
>   Jose\Loader->loadAndDecryptUsingKey('eyJhbGciOiJSU0E...',
>   Object(Jose\Object\JWK), Array, Array, NULL) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\z3nth10n-PHP\api.php(9):
>   include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\z3nth10n-PHP\libs\jose\Decrypter.php on line 80

I have been looking in the code for so much time, and I have realized that the problem isn't in the code, the problem is in the token generated. And I don't know what can I do, you can test it here.

[Encoding a word](https://qbz28b-user.freehosting.host/api.php?action=encrypt-jose&input=hola)...

... and then, [decrypting it](https://qbz28b-user.freehosting.host/api.php?action=decrypt-jose&input=eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUCIsImVuYyI6IkEyNTZHQ00iLCJ6aXAiOiJERUYifQ.ehUYdSf8nB6aE7nA3l3tNGQ8RWyGFfQVdbABHX3ag3aRxd0ckFQ463PiWlG-vMm6kalhAg0fudkZPNy5bHs2q-E00wt3i2iFJQgmrEaqXoM4-3RC7tJMZ4U3Txa1xlrlx0A0SZScoSPL0TbVRBJ-edKjqOOLAvTKMhDd-dt7JTsDObO3F3gRmxAOmDQe1areqsnKwj-2kzI4KV0NBsibd3UuvlGarKr34CwBm0aGJgxEYoN1PfYweZzsiseQJdlNtTyXwYUlrZZSgdQTA_NhrjnpGmtpqVJYuDA3I2fXGZoJ4aREaTeJbSv6xK2q_4fw5svTsr6tNraBiNepaPHLJHFGjxphw8jBSQHlTHecOttYttWjeEGUioCx5kDnfztrWdcCk8zZZAlLUKMg_5YeoHC8GOBYsUdDZfmJFcfmGPheMG7I_4Ck01QigRlaqKxF3kq0zcqbuLYKXnVMEBH69iNILqHO7E8LP_PNGiiYLOL3hn0BZHnNYWvMpMdHzw07Q4It1EEXpcoTdwJiwXu57NMZqAS7PoBxN3Q_1C9Ou_cIg5JQtS_ICBuUiz3SxJ6zs-l98swS2LITheFtvljCERjVrbIEccGYLSfeXiX_ShZCjJyGz0MbA37BLkXONj_npmX1_Z4IgvzeMfESmhBHYujqy3nqShkFl3QDXtvWsDA.F3YuJTE_AQOT9Pml.KDMsPJEp.Bjky3j3N64TJhJnEiChouA).

Any suggestions to look at?

Comment: The examples from JOSE (php) show a different way to create the key. Maybe is this problem: https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose/blob/master/examples/Encrypt1.php

Comment: I already have checked this example, the first method only loads the key, the second method does the work, this only generated a different output that can be decrypted with PHP. But the problem occurs when I try to decompile a C# token with PHP.